# Flexible children with one element expanded outside top border of parent container

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout where there are two adjacent elements inside a main container - the first, a block of text and the second, an image that expands outside the *top border only* of the container, by say 20px. I want both the text container (A) and the image (B) to be flexible widths, while both respecting the padding of the outer container.

The markup looks something like this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h1>Heading</h11>
    <p>Subheading</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the  to grow taller than the container but still be pinned to the bottom right of the container, without the container growing larger than the second `<div>`. Is there a neat way to do this?

[Desired Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIVXC.jpg)

Comment: Negative margin-top on the image? (Btw., would be more helpful if you showed actual HTML markup, and not whatever this is supposed to be.)

Comment: @CBroe good idea, didn't think to change the custom styled-components blocks before pasting in here - updated now. Negative-margin on the image would move it upwards but without it being "pinned" to the bottom-right. 

Right now the closest I've gotten is by applying a `transform: scale(2); transform-origin: bottom right;`, but obviously that prevents the left text block from respecting the space the image has expanded to occupy. Any idea how I might get around that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the image not being pinned to the bottom right? https://jsfiddle.net/k3s96gjh/

Comment: It looks like it works in that case, but as the paragraph text gets longer (it is in my case, I should've defined in that way in the example markup) and as the image shrinks/grows, the image will be pulled upwards, e.g https://jsfiddle.net/50Lpj4h1/1/

Comment: But that image would not stick to the bottom left, even without any negative margin. If the image is not larger than the text, then this does not match the scenario you showed on your initial image in the first place. Not sure what you’d _want_ this to look like in that situation.